# How to run c++ script written by different version of visual studio in cmd?

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

Now I'm trying to use python subprocess module to spawn two sub-processes, one of them running a c++ source code using Microsoft Visual studio 2010 and another one running a c++ source code using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012. How can I achieve that?

The python code will be like:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['run code1 with visual studio 2010'])
subprocess.Popen(['run code2 with visual studio 2012'])
```

The reason why I want to do this is that I cannot simply combine these two source code together, since they use different visual studio system runtime. If anyone know the answer or how to fix that runtime problem, please give me some advice, really appreciated!!

Comment: C++ is not a scripting language so I'm curious what scripting engine you're using to execute them.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious My mistake, sorry I am only a freshman in coding.

Comment: You'll need to compile and link the code before you can actually run it. If you have a project file you can use MS Build to kick it off and specify the configuration you want it to compile with.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I don't know if this would work, but would it be possible to separate the code into 2 different executables and then have them called? I'm guessing that would be system intensive.

Comment: Can't see the code so no idea and really have no idea what you're really trying to accomplish. Anyway I'm out.

Comment: I think you need to elaborate "since they use different visual studio system runtime" before anyone can figure out what in the heck youre talking about